# How to store a type for later comparison

Tags: c++, c++11, types, lambda, c++14

First off my use case, as I may think in the wrong direction: I want to create a map that maps a value to types. So for example:

```
Map<std::string> map;
map.insert<int, double, char>("Hey");
auto string = map.at<int, double, char>();
```

This alone is fairly easy to do with `std::type_index`. However, I want to add the possibility to match types that are not exact the searched ones, when they are convertible. So the following should also return `"Hey"`, as `float` can be converted to `double`:

```
auto string = map.at<int, float, char>();
```

I can't use `type_index` for this case as `std::is_convertible` only works directly on types. [This would be the version without conversion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a5f30dc1917f770), but as far as it seems it's not easily possible to add conversion handling into it without major changes.

---

My current attempt looks kind of like the following, please note that this is not working and just shows what I have tried to implement:

```
template<typename T> 
class Map {
    T value; 
    std::vector<Map<T>> children; // all the children of the current node.
                                  // in the above example, if this was
                                  // the int node, the only child 
                                  // would be the double node

    template<typename T1>
    constexpr bool is_convertible() const {
        return std::is_convertible<__T__, T1>::value; // this isn't applicable
                                                  // since __T__ can't be
                                                  // stored (this nodes
                                                  // type)
    }

public:
    template<typename T1, typename... Tn>
    void insert(T&& value) {
        // iterate through/create the child nodes until the last template param
    }
    template<typename T1, typename... Tn>
    T& at() {
        // iterate through thechild nodes until a matching child is found
        // either exact match or a convertible 

        for(auto &c: children) {
            // if the above function would work
            if(c.template is_convertible<T1>()) { 
                return c.template at<Tn...>();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Now I'm at my wits end how to achieve this. I thought of implementing lambdas as comparator functions, but while the lambda can store the type of the current node, it can't accept a template parameter on call to compare to.

Is there some C+1y generic lambda comparator magic, or even an easier way?

Comment: Are the key-value pairs created at runtime or only at compile time? What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then this idea depends on virtual template functions, which are effectively not usable for in this situation.

Comment: @Svalorzen At compile time.

Comment: Although I'm completely baffled at the `c.template get<Tn...>(value)` line, that contradicts my understanding.  This question makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Appleshell: Well, `vector` doesn't do anything at compile time, so the code contradicts what you're telling us.

Comment: Can you show the code _without_ conversions so we can try to figure out what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can't you just create a template struct map which takes a variadic number of template parameters, and then specialize in advance any combination you might want? I have to insist though that if with this you are trying to solve some real problem you may be going the wrong way.

Comment: @MooingDuck Virtual template functions were exactly my first thought, but apparently that concept does not exist in C++. As for the get, that should have been `at`, and without the value. Copy and paste mistake, I'll edit it out.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'll write that version again, one moment.

Comment: At the close vote: I think the first paragraph makes it pretty clear what I want to achieve. The second paragraph is only to show what I have tried.

Comment: @Appleshell: There is nothing about "associating types with strings" that makes me think "I'll make a tree-based container, where every node is associated with `std::string`".  The code seems 100% unrelated to the first paragraph.  The code has no `std::type_index` in it, nor any place where I would obviously put it

Comment: @MooingDuck Here's the version without conversion: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a5f30dc1917f770

Comment: @Svalorzen I can't specify the possible combinations in advance, this will be used as a generic interface.

Comment: @Appleshell: Oh, so this isn't allowed? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e95fe62ec704adf6

Comment: @MooingDuck If something like that would generically be generated, it would be :) But the `insert` method like it currently stands (its declaration) is important.

Comment: Store a list of all types under considerstion (both insert and at usage).  Use of a type not in this list is a compile time error.  Build a convertable matrix from this list to this list (by index say).  Have insert store tuples of indexes, and at use the convertable matrix to search for matches at run time.  Not fast, requires central repository (list) of types, requires tonnes of metaprogramming, and probably an answer to a question that is best solved using the answer to another question.  (I assume you are emulating overloading on run time registered methods)

Comment: No conversions, but this is a simplified/faster version of what you already had: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9bdef24398e45109

Comment: Keep in mind that lambda expressions are not a panacea. They allow for more concise code (where everything is inline), but otherwise do not bring additional functionality. I.e. everything they do can be replicated out of line. What you want is not possible (at its most general) due to the compilation model of C++ and lack of runtime reflection. Types defined in a TU are out of reach from other TUs, in a sense.

Comment: @LucDanton Yeah, I figured. I worked around this by manually registering the possible conversion manually and then just comparing the stored type_indices with the registered ones. Although, lambdas (and generally, variadic template metaprogramming for that matter) *are* a great solution for 90% of the problems I came across up to this point ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this does what you want, there's ample space for extension and for creating template specialization that attach to any type combination you want. It's not super-pretty, but it can probably be refactored a bit and beautified.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Args>
struct map {
};

template <>
struct map<int, float, char> {
    static constexpr char value[] = "int float char";
};
constexpr char map<int,float,char>::value[];

template <typename T>
struct map<int, T> {
    static constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, char>::type value[] = "int, T";
};
template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, char>::type map<int,T>::value[];

int main() {
    std::string v  = map<int,float,char>::value;
    std::string w  = map<int,int>::value;
    std::string w2 = map<int,unsigned>::value;
    // std::string w3 = map<int,float>::value; Won't compile

    std::cout << v << "\n";
    std::cout << w << "\n";
    std::cout << w2 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's unfortunately not applicable in this case, being able to add values via method call (`insert` in my code) is important.

Comment: @Appleshell You said that the keys are added during compile time.. In addition why? You are stating a very vague problem with lots of hidden requirements. You should maybe state more about it so that solutions can be adequately proposed.

Comment: Yes, I understood you wrong, I honestly apologize. I read it as a question if the types are known at compile time thus making things like stored lambdas viable or something in that matter, and I figured I corrected myself with my last comment under the question. I hope I made my intentions better understandable with the additional code I added.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some weird code using boost::fusion that comes close to doing what you want:

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/insert.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/for_each.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>
template <std::size_t Value1, std::size_t Value2>
struct MinSizeT {
    static const std::size_t value = (Value1 > Value2) ? Value2 : Value1;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2, std::size_t N>
struct TupleIsConvertibleHelper {
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<typename std::tuple_element<N - 1, T1>::type, typename std::tuple_element<N - 1, T2>::type>::value && TupleIsConvertibleHelper<T1, T2, N - 1>::value;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct TupleIsConvertibleHelper<T1, T2, 0> {
    static const bool value = true;
};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
bool TupleIsConvertible() { // Return true if all types in T1 are convertible to their corresponding type in T2
    if (std::tuple_size<T1>::value != std::tuple_size<T2>::value)
        return false;
    constexpr std::size_t minSize = MinSizeT<std::tuple_size<T1>::value, std::tuple_size<T2>::value>::value;
    return TupleIsConvertibleHelper<T1, T2, minSize>::value;
}
template<typename MapInserter>
class Map {
    MapInserter mc;
    template<typename... Types>
    struct do_at {
        template <typename T>
        void operator()(T const& x) const { // Find an exact match or the last convertible match
            typedef std::tuple<Types...> t1;
            typedef typename T::first_type t2;
            if (exactMatch)
                return;
            if (std::is_same<t1, t2>::value) {
                exactMatch = true;
                value = x.second;
            }
            else if (TupleIsConvertible<t1, t2>())
                value = x.second;
        }
        mutable bool exactMatch;
        mutable typename MapInserter::value_type value;
        do_at() : exactMatch(false) {}
    };
public:
    Map(MapInserter _mc) : mc(_mc) { }
    template<typename... Types>
    typename MapInserter::value_type at() {
        do_at<Types...> res;
        boost::fusion::for_each(mc.data->map, res);
        return res.value;
    }
};
template<typename ValueType, typename MapType = boost::fusion::map<>, typename ParentType = void*>
struct MapInserter {
    typedef ValueType value_type;
    struct Helper {
        MapType map;
        std::shared_ptr<ParentType> parent; // Must keep parent alive because fusion is lazy.
        Helper() = default;
        Helper(MapType&& _map, std::shared_ptr<ParentType> _parent) : map(std::move(_map)), parent(_parent) {}
    };
    std::shared_ptr<Helper> data;
    template<typename... KeyTypes>
    auto Insert(ValueType value) -> MapInserter<ValueType, decltype(boost::fusion::insert(data->map, boost::fusion::end(data->map), boost::fusion::make_pair<std::tuple<KeyTypes...>>(value))), Helper> {
        auto newMap = boost::fusion::insert(data->map, boost::fusion::end(data->map), boost::fusion::make_pair<std::tuple<KeyTypes...>>(value));
        return MapInserter<ValueType, decltype(newMap), Helper>(std::move(newMap), data);
    }
    MapInserter() : data(std::make_shared<Helper>()) { }
    MapInserter(MapType&& _map, std::shared_ptr<ParentType> _parent) : data(std::make_shared<Helper>(std::move(_map), _parent)) {}
    MapInserter(MapInserter&&) = default;
    MapInserter(const MapInserter&) = default;
};
int main() {
    auto mc = MapInserter<std::string>().
        Insert<int, char, float>("***int, char, float***").
        Insert<float, double>("***float, double***").
        Insert<int>("***int***").
        Insert<unsigned, bool>("***unsigned, bool***");
    Map<decltype(mc)> map(mc);
    std::cout << map.at<int, char, float>() << std::endl; // "***int, char, float***"
    std::cout << map.at<int, char, double>() << std::endl; // "***int, char, float***"
    std::cout << map.at<char>() << std::endl; // "***int***"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have to admit I see no reason why this would ever be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class...>struct types { typedef types type; };
template<class T, class types>struct type_index;
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct type_index<T,types<T, Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned,0>
{};
template<class T, class T0, class...Ts>
struct type_index<T,types<T0, Ts...>>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned,type_index<T,types<Ts...>::value+1>
{};

template<template<class>class filter, class types_in, class types_out=types<>, class details=void>
struct filter;

template<template<class>class filter, class T0, class... Ts, class... Zs>
struct filter<filter, types<T0,types...>, types<Zs...>,
  typename std::enable_if< filter<T0>::value >::type
>: filter<filter, types<types...>, types<Zs...,T0>>
{};
template<template<class>class filter, class T0, class... Ts, class... Zs>
struct filter<filter, types<T0,types...>, types<Zs...>,
  typename std::enable_if< !filter<T0>::value >::type
>: filter<filter, types<types...>, types<Zs...>>
{};
template<template<class>class filter, class... Zs>
struct filter<filter, types<>, types<Zs...>,
  void
>: types<Zs...>
{};

template<typename T>
struct convertable_to_test {
  template<typename U>
  using test = std::is_convertible<U, T>;
};

template<class T, class types>
struct get_convertable_to_types:filter< convertable_to_test<T>::template test, types> {};
```

which is a start.

Create a master `types<Ts...>` of all of the types your system supports.  Call this `SupportedTypes`.

Map `types<Ts...>` to `std::vector<unsigned>` of each type offset in the above list.  Now you can store a collection of types at runtime.  Call this a runtime type vector.

When adding an entry `types<Args...>` to the map, run `get_convertable_to_types` on each type in `types<Args...>`, and build a cross product in `types< types<...>... >`.  Store the resulting exponential number of runtime type vectors in your implementation details map.

When you query with `types<Ts...>`, conver to the runtime type vector, and look it up in the implementation details map.  And done!

An alternative approach would be to write `get_convertable_from_types`, and do the mapping to an exponential number of `types<Ts...>` at the query point, convert each to a runtime type vector.  When adding stuff to the map, store only one runtime type vector.  This has slower lookup performance, but faster setup performance, and uses far less memory.

I was going to finish this, but got busy.